# JQuery script not working despite working in the console

Tags: jquery, console

I am attempting to make the entire div of a Nivo slider on [this](http://brasileirosreformados.com/) site clickable so the visitor can navigate to a featured article.  I developed the following script within Chrome's console to work out the bugs.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function(){      
    $j( '.nivo-slice' ).click(function(){
        window.location = $j('.nivo-html-caption').find('a:first').attr('href');
    });
});
```

This script works perfectly when entered via the console, however when inserted into a js file (custom.js) and included in the footer, it doesn't work at all.  If you view the page source, the file shows up correctly in the markup and Chrome's inspector flags no errors. I'm confused, anyone have ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: When I look at your page in chrome I see 4 javascript errors.  Fix them and I expect your script will work.

Comment: Chrome gives:[jquery.form] terminating; zero elements found by selector

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error that i see in the console

> Chrome gives:[jquery.form] terminating; zero elements found by selector

Comes from this line

```
$('div.wpcf7 > form').ajaxForm
```

This is located in your scripts.js file. It cant find `div.wpcf7 > form` hence, throws that error.

As far as your code goes, i don't see an element with class `.nivo-slice`.

Comment: And another error at line 92: `delay: , // one second delay on mouseout`

Answer (score 0):

There is no argument for the delay:

when you call the slider. It is just blank. It needs a value.